# Jquery cycle plugin customization

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-cycle

I am struggling to customize jquery cycle plugin. What I want is when the slider reaches last slide it will stop sliding to first slide again.This is working fine.

But the problem is when I am on first slide and then click the third slide then it's not ending there rather it goes back to first slide.

My jquery code is here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

     $('.slider1 ul.horizontal').cycle({
        fx:     'scrollHorz',
        speed:  500,
        pause:                  1,
        pauseOnPagerHover: true,
        width: "100%",
        easeOut: 'easeOutBack',
        cleartypeNoBg: true,
        pager: 'ul.pager',  
        autostop: 2,
        autostopCount:3,
        startingSlide: 0,
        after:   onAfter,        
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
              return '<li><a href="#"></a></li>';
        }

    });

     function onAfter()
     {


         if ($('.slider_content').css('display') == 'block') 
        {       
             if ($('li#lastslide').css('display') == 'block') { 
                 $('.slider1 ul.horizontal').cycle('pause');         
                  $('.controlbutton').stop().fadeIn(500);                
             }
             else
             {
                 if($('.question_slide').css('right') != '0px')
                 {
                     $('.controlbutton').fadeOut(100);
                 }          
             } 
        } 


     }
});
```

I think there should be some pagination click event.I have checked the plugin options reference page but can't under stand how to tell the plugin that this is the last slide and don't go back to the first slide.

Any idea please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944312/any-way-to-make-jquery-cycle-not-loop-when-reaching-the-end-or-the-beginning

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution is to use nowrap:  1